# How to stop a regex from being greedy from the left

Tags: regex

I know you can stop a regex from being greedy from the right using the "?" sign. But what about the left side ? Suppose I have this:

```
X test X junk X Hello Y junk2 Y
```

How to force it to select only "Hello" between X and Y ?

My regex so far:

```
/X(.*?)Y/g
```

Thank you.

Comment: The greedy operator is doing exactly what it is supposed to do.  From the first X, select the minimum of characters to a Y.

Comment: @RobertSlaney: how would you translate `From the most right X, select..` in regex ?

Comment: That depends on the regex engine your are using and whether you have backwards assertions ( javascript doesn't ).  Nambi's solution below finds all text between an X and Y that doesn't contain and X or Y

Comment: Technically @xdazz is a better match as you asked for it without spaces

Comment: If php supports them, could you please give an example of a backward assertion? I have very large html files, and using the `[^XY]` technique making the query even larger probably isn't a good idea

Comment: php only allows fixed length ( no *, ? or + ) in the lookbehind assertion, so you can't do it in that engine.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about [^XY], that is a straight forward match selector for an regex engine

Answer (score 1):

You could use the patten like: `/X\s+([^XY]+)\s+Y/g`.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use this Pattern `X([^XY]+)Y/g`

Answer (score 1):

try this pattern:    `/.*X(.*?)Y/g` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fZ1mL3)

Comment: @Reacen look at Demo Match1 should be what you're looking for

Comment: If you remove the global flag it does, but depending on the regex engine there might be more than 1 match.  In javascript the second match contains the string " Hello "  `X test X junk X Hello Y junk2 Y".match( /.*X(.*?)Y/)[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the target string before searching and then search for a reversed regex.  In python:

```
m=re.search(r'Y(.*?)X',reversed(s))
if m:
    return reversed(m.group(1))
```

Comment: Same issue, there are 2 "Y"s.  The answer will be X Hello Y junk2 Y

Comment: I missed the second Y on the right. This idea will work only if you have a unique pattern on the right.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in perl:

```
$_='X test X junk X Hello Y junk2 Y';
if (/X(?!.*X)(.*?)Y/) {
    print "$1\n";
}
else {
    print "No match!\n";
}
```

The `(?!.*X)` makes sure that that the first X is not followed by a second one.